# How to remove span onclick or on modify?

Tags: javascript, css, html

How do I write a JS function to remove the span on click and just retain the inner text ?

```
    ​<span class="test" onclick="removespan(this);">Data in red</span>
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    ​removespan = function(e)​{
                            alert(e.innerText);
                            }​
    CSS : ​span.test{color:red;}
```

onclick I would like to remove the span and just retain the inner text .
Infact I would like to have a onmodify event ...that removes the span .
The purpose is to remove a spellchecker span class in WYSIWYG editor .

Comment: Is this span is the only element in its parent node ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the span is the only child element inside its parent node

```
<div>
    <span class="test" onclick="removespan(this);">Data in red</span>
</div>


removespan = function(span) {
    span.parentNode.innerHTML = span.innerHTML;
}
```

Otherwise use this function

```
removespan = function(span) {
    span.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(span.innerHTML), span);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested in an "expanded" version of Diode's second option:

```
function removespan(span) {
    // Get the text contents of the clicked span
    var span_contents = span.innerHTML;
    // Get the parent node of the clicked span
    var span_parent = span.parentNode;
    // Create a new text node in the DOM to hold the text contents
    var text_node = document.createTextNode(span.innerHTML);
    // Replace the clicked span node with your newly created text node
    span_parent.replaceChild(text_node, span);

    // Alternatively, do the above in one line...
    // span.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(span.innerHTML), span);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="test"></span>

y=doc.getElementsById("test");

y.getParent().removeChild(y);
```